# jQuery use .live with jquery-keyfilter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, keyfilter

I am using [jquery-keyfilter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-keyfilter/) plugin to mask textbox inputs.
However the textboxes are added to the page dynamically and I cannot figure out how to apply the key filter to them.

I have tried

```
$('#myelement').live('keyfilter', myFunction );
```

Also

```
$('#myelement').live('keyfilter', /regex/);
```

Kai: comment helps, but it seems my problem is still not solved

I want a keyfilter like this

```
(/^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$/);
```

that will only accept currency/money values but it seems like jquery-keyfilter does not work with this regex. Is this something I am doing wrong or should I look at using another plugin or just code it myself?

Comment: Ok seems like keyfilter needs the entire string to match so my above regex will not work if I start typing $.  So I had to end up with this regex /[\d\$\,\.]/   which allows only certain characters but they can be entered in any order.   This will do until I write a function to do exactly what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"keyfilter" is not an event and you can NOT use live().
According to API of the plugin, it should be

```
$('#myelement').keyfilter(function(c) { return c != 'a'; }); 

$('#myelement').keyfilter(/[\dA-F]/);
```

Comment: Thank you I did not realise you can only use live for events

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for non-first character

```
  
$("#myelement").live("keypress", function(){  
  $(this).keyfilter((/^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$/);  
});
```

Below solution works for input field already clicked

```
  
$("#myelement").live("click", function(){    
  $(this).keyfilter((/^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$/);  
});
```

Comment: This does not work see here
http://jsbin.com/esezi/edit   it will not allow me to enter a $ sign by itself or a comma  test it here yourself http://regexr.com?2rqsu

I have it working now  for key entry using /[\d\$\,\.]/   and I just use jQuery validation plugin with the final regex for when the field loses focus. Sure I could write a regex to do exactly what I want on keypress but eh. It would be too long and nasty to maintain